# Web api controller with two get methods having same paramteres

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I am building a Http service using asp.net web api, I have two get methods in the controller with the same parameters, I can't figure out how to define the route the matches both methods, I can call only one of them and for the other I get an error that no action method was found on the controller.
Here are the routes defined

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "default",
         routeTemplate: "{controller}/{lang}",
         defaults: new { lang = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "details",
         routeTemplate: "{controller}/{lang}/{action}/{id}");
```

and the methods in the controller:

```
public IQueryable<RecipeDTO> Get(string lang)
{

}

[HttpGet]
public RecipeDTO Details(string lang, int id)
{

}

[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<RecipeDTO> Random(string lang, int count)
{


}
```

You see the methods Details and Random have the same parameters, I can make the following calls:

controller-name/en    (which matches the first get method)

controller-name/en/details/1    (which matches the details method)

but when I try:

controller-name/en/random/5

I get the error no action method was found on the controller, how can I fix that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API is strict about matching route variables with parameter names. You can try changing your action to the following(Here we are aliasing the `count` parameter):

`[HttpGet]

public IQueryable<RecipeDTO> Random(string lang, [FromUri(Name = "id")]int count)`